# How do google sheets skipping 5 row with formula?

Tags: google-sheets

[How do  google sheets skipping 5 row with formula ?][1]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34EE0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place in `C3` and then apply down the column

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("'6'!Cn:Kn","n",ROW()*5-13)))
```